# How do you enqueue a Visual Basic script using wp_enqueue_script?

Tags: wp-enqueue-script

Internet Explorer will have errors with VB script files en-queued using wp_enqueue_script.  This is probably because the output of enqueue script set the script type to 'language/javascript'. Are there any solutions besides manually including the VB script with the theme?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`WP_Script` always adds `text/javascript`](http://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/branches/3.0/wp-includes/class.wp-scripts.php#L70) to the `<script>` tag, and applies no filter before it returns, there is not much you can do there. You could try to create a subclass of `WP_Scripts` that has this functionality. If you change the global `$wp_scripts` to your new class, this *might* work.

Comment: Heh, seconds ahead of me. :)

Comment: @Rarst: Thanks for recognizing [who has the fastest gun](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2008/10/solving-the-fastest-gun-in-the-west-problem/) :-)

Comment: In the end I add an action using the admin_head hook

Comment: Why create a entire class, when you can just insert the `<script>` tag yourself ? `WP_Script`'s purpose is to minimize conflicts between javascripts. Chances that you find a plugin or theme using vbscript, and the same one you're trying to use, are 0.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately script type is hardcoded in `WP_Scripts` class. If you need extensive queue management for your VBS scripts you will have to extend that class and use own wrapper functions for VB separately.